# Help with a Mathematica front end touchscreen problem

Tags: front-end, notebooks, user-interface

I really like using my Windows 10 touchscreen to move around in websites, documents, etc. It doesn't work in Mathematica. Can that be fixed by changing a global notebook setting, or is it something deeper in Mathematica? I'm using a Dell 17 inch Inspiron 7746 (bought recently) running on Windows 10 Home. I installed the latest Windows 10 update last week. The machine has 16.0 GB memory and a 64-bit operating system running on a x64-based processor.  I haven't had touch screen problems with other  applications: Edge, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, MS Outlook, Excel, etc.

Perhaps this seems trivial because it doesn't seem to be about the Wolfram Language. But it is about the Mathematica interface (the front end), which is intrinsic to using Mathematica. As more people start working with touchscreens, this desire to interact with notebooks will be more widespread. It's really useful when working with a large notebook on a laptop.

As a supplementary comment, I have discovered that touch scrolling does work in some (a few) notebooks. I have absolutely no clue about the difference between them.

Comment: Have you seen the **Touch Devices** section in  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CustomInterfaceConstruction.html?

Comment: No. I didn't know it existed.  I'll look.

Comment: I looked at it earlier. These functions allow a notebook to use touch locations to as input to a function. Useful if you're writing code to detect where the  screen has been touched, but I don't want to right an event handler. I want the notebook to scroll up/down right/left with touch gestures.