# Mathematica notebook interface and touch screens

Tags: notebooks, interface

This questions has been ask before over two years ago. There are yet no answers. It is a simple question, does the Mathematica notebook interface support touch?  If it does how do you use settings to get it to work?   It appears to work for me on some Notebooks, but not on others.  On those for which it works I can scroll up and down and sideways. However, I have not been able to figure out why it works on only some Notebooks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange! Could you give a link to where it has been asked before?

Comment: Possibly related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101089/3066

Comment: When you talk about "Notebooks", are you referring to the Mathematica front-end app or to notebook computers?

Comment: Sorry I should have included a link to previous question.  The question was asked before at this link:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101089/help-with-a-mathematica-front-end-touchscreen-problem   by @George-Wolfe

Comment: When I say Notebook I meant to say the Mathematica Front-End Interface.  Also I am running Mathematica on a Win 10 Surface Pro 4.

Comment: It seems like MMA notebooks (<= V11.1) interpret all touch events as cursor movement (i.e., as if they were entered by a mouse rather than a finger).  It does not seem to interpret gestures (which one expects to be treated as scrolling, zooming, etc) in any special way.  FWIW, one is able scroll with touch by tapping or dragging the horizontal or vertical scroll bars -- this is just far less convenient and user-friendly than using a scrolling gesture.  **Do you have any examples of MMA notebooks which contradict this statement?**

Answer (score -1):

Regarding Mathematica for macOS, I haven't encountered any problems about touch screen. It works fine. I use an iPad as an external display, so I can use touch screen of the iPad to scroll Mathematica notebooks on iPad.

I haven't never used iPad as external display on Windows, fortunately Duet Display supports Windows as well.

https://www.duetdisplay.com

Comment: It's nice to know this works, but my guess is that this has more to do with the application (Duet Display?) you use to mirror/extend your display onto an iPad, rather than the way the MMA responds to touch commands.  I'm betting that this application converts gestures into scrolling commands before sending them to the OS and MMA -- otherwise, how could it work with an OS that doesn't have any touch support?

Comment: In particular, I don't think it would help a user like OP (or myself) who is running a Windows device with a built-in touch screen.